# Saving eBay and Banggood web pages including description photos

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, save-as

I make many purchases on on-line stores such as eBay and Banggood etc. and i like to save the web page, as is, at the time of purchase, since some time in the future the items may not be available.  I am looking for some software to save the page complete, in one file (not a folder full of files), any format, as long as i can clearly view it in the future using MS Windows.  I have tried a large number of applications and formats, but none can cope with the photos in the description section that are found on sites such as eBay and Banggood. They save the page, but the description photos are missing.  There are often other adverts on these pages, i don't require the advert information saved. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser LPS,  The recommending software can be viewed  as spam and is handled on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . Have you tried IE .mht file? Please take a couple of minutes and read: again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to save the page in HTML format with all pictures/scripts/etc. included, which is very complicated, just save a big screenshot of the whole page.

There are tools like [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fireshot/) which allow you to save a screenshot of the whole page, not just the part visible on your screen.

Comment: I have tried a number of screenshot applications but the one you recommended does exactly what i wanted.  Thanks !